# ASP.NET Core MVC : passing arabic digit as zero to controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```
public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
```

Model property type is `decimal`, and this is the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Latitude, "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter ...", autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty-string as the second argument to `TextBoxFor`?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Longitude, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter ...", autocomplete = "off" }) i was removed it ,but it didn't making sense

Comment: What does your `<form>` look like? And post your **full** model classes and controller actions.

Comment: Edit your question, don't post code in comments.

Comment: Dai ! Do you have a solution to My problem

Comment: No, because you haven't provided anywhere near enough detail to diagnose the problem. Also, you haven't actually said what the problem is...

Comment: Mr Dai! When I write Arabic digits into Latitude Text box like that(۱۲۳.۲۱) textboxfor passing it as zero to the controller, that is the problem

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The demo built only with the information you provide works fine.